# Pass Multer validation error to React Component

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, multer

I am learning `Multer` along with `Redux` and `React`.

My `express` router is like

```
router.post('/upload', addressController.uploadImage);
```

My `Multer` code is like below

```
const uploadImage = (req, res, next) => {

    const storage = multer.diskStorage({
        destination: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, './uploads/');
        },
        filename: function(req, file, cb) {
            cb(null, Date.now() + '-' + file.originalname);
        }
    });

    const fileFilter = (req, file, cb) => {
        if (file.mimetype === 'image/jpeg' || file.mimetype === 'image/png') {
            cb(null, true);
        } else {
            cb(new Error('Try to upload .jpeg or .png file.'), false);
        }
    };

    const upload = multer({
        storage: storage,
        limits: {
            fileSize: 1024 * 1024 * 5
        },
        fileFilter: fileFilter
    }).single('addressImage');

    upload(req, res, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            // An error occurred when uploading
            res.status(500).json({
                message: error // I would like to send error from Here.
            });
            console.log(error);
        } else {
            if (req.file.filename === res.req.res.req.file.filename) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'File uploaded',
                    file: req.file.filename
                });
            }
            return;
        }
    });
}
```

My Action is like below

```
export const uploadImage = (formData, id, config) => dispatch => {
  return Axios.post('/api/address/upload', formData, config)
    .then(response => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'uploadImage',
        payload: response.data
      });
    })
    .catch(error => {
      dispatch({
        type: 'uploadImage',
        payload: error // I would like to pass error through here.
      });
      return false;
    });
};
```

My Reducer is like below

```
const addressReducer = (state = initialState, action) => {
    switch (action.type) {
        case 'getAddresses': {
            return {
                ...state,
                controlModal: action.payload.valueModal,
                address: action.payload.addressData
            };
        }
        case 'uploadImage': {
            return {
                ...state,
                uploadImage: action.payload 
            };
        }
        default:
            return state;
    }
};
```

I would like to get error in my component is like below

```
render() {
        console.log(this.props.uploadImage);
}


const mapStateToProps = state => ( {
    uploadImage: state.addressReducer.uploadImage
} );


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(ModalElement);
```

My console output is like below

[image]

**How can I get `Try to upload .jpeg or .png file.` error in my React component while I try to upload file without .jpeg and .png extension ?**

Comment: its 500 internal server error so, can you please post the error log you are getting in server side?

Comment: Thanks @VikashSingh. If I use this code `upload(req, res, function(error) {
        if (error) {
            console.log(error); // I need to pass this error to React
        } else {
            if (req.file.filename === res.req.res.req.file.filename) {
                res.status(200).json({
                    message: 'File uploaded',
                    file: req.file.filename
                });
            }
            return;
        }
    });`.

I am getting this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/mJitG.png

Comment: There is very nice tutorial which will resolve your doubts related to multer please go through this once : https://scotch.io/tutorials/express-file-uploads-with-multer
I hope this will help you. Further If you face more challenges , please let me know.

Comment: according to screenshot it is failing at file validation. are you uploading .jpeg or .png image file ?

Comment: Thanks @VikashSingh. I would like to get that file validation message in React component.

Comment: Thanks @VikashSingh. I saw your tutorial previously but this is not focusing on my issue.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/191213/discussion-between-vikash-singh-and-abu-abu).

Answer (score 3):

you don't have to send 500 status code instead you should send 400

```
 res.status(400).json({
            message: error // I would like to send error from Here.
        });
```

Comment: Thanks @Vikash Singh.  I used this code `res.status(200).json({
                error
            }); ` and got this error https://i.stack.imgur.com/s9Ax8.png.

Comment: It tells storage error this might be due to incorrect way of giving directory path or directory permissions. Try giving complete full absolute path and assign suitable permissions.

Comment: Thanks @Vikash Singh. Directory path is correct. If I use .png or .jpeg everything works fine. I would like to pass the validation message to React. If I use `if (error) {
            console.log(error);
        }` the message is printed in Terminal. Thanks.

Comment: `res.status(400).json({ error }); ` this should solve

Comment: Hi, Can you please expand the `request` object in your previous screenshot and show me whats there in it?

Answer (score 3):

The `Error` does not resolve to a valid json when it is passed through the `res.json()` and thus, it is stripped out.

So, to access the message `"Try to upload .jpeg or .png file."`, you should update the `Multer` code like this:

```
if (error) {
    // An error occurred when uploading
    res.status(500).json({
        /** error.message => "Try to upload .jpeg or .png file." */
        message: error.message // I would like to send error from Here.
    });
    console.log(error);
}
```

If you try to upload the file using Postman, you would have the following API response:

```
{
    "message": "Try to upload .jpeg or .png file."
}
```

Once you have that, you can change your `dispatch()` like:

```
.catch(error => {
    dispatch({
        type: "uploadImage",
        /** error.data is the response. We want the `message` property from it */
        payload: error.data.message // I would like to pass error through here.
    });
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's how I was able to accomplish it for an avatar microservice I created to work alongside my main application.

**WARNING**: This explanation goes through the entire flow, so it may be lengthy and redundant if you already understand it.

---

### Create an axios configuration.

First, you must create an `axios` configuration. By default `axios` won't show the `err` returned by the server, instead, it'll just display a generic `Error` object. You'll need to set up an **`interceptor`**.

**utils/axiosConfig.js**

```
import get from 'lodash/get';
import axios from 'axios';

export const avatarAPI = axios.create({
  baseURL: 'http://localhost:4000/api/', // this makes it easier so that any request will be prepended with this baseURL
});

avatarAPI.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response, // returns the server response
  error => {
    const err = get(error, ['response', 'data', 'err']); // this checks if "error.response.data.err" is present (this is the error returned from the server); VERY IMPORTANT: this "err" property is specified in our express middlewares/controllers, so please pay attention to the naming convention.

    return err ? Promise.reject(err) : Promise.reject(error.message); // if the above is present, return the server error, else return a generic Error object
  },
);
```

---

### The flow from client to server back to client.

#### Client

A user submits a form with `formData` and this triggers an `action` creator:

**uploadAvatar thunk action creator (which is a promise waiting for a `response` or `error` from our server)**:

```
import { avatarAPI } from '../utils/axiosConfig'; // import the custom axios configuration that was created above
import * as types from 'types';

const uploadAvatar = formData => dispatch =>
  avatarAPI
    .post(`avatar/create`, formData) // this makes a POST request to our server -- this also uses the baseURL from the custom axios configuration, which is the same as "http://localhost:4000/api/avatar/create"
    .then(({ data }) => {
      dispatch({ type: types.SET_CURRENT_AVATAR, payload: data.avatarurl });
    })
    .catch(err => // this will return our server "err" string if present, otherwise it'll return a generic Error object. IMPORTANT: Just in case we get a generic Error object, we'll want to convert it to a string (otherwise, if it passes the generic Error object to our reducer, stores it to redux state, passes it to our connected component, which then tries to display it... it'll cause our app to crash, as React can't display objects)
      dispatch({ type: types.SERVER_ERROR, payload: err.toString() }),
    );
```

#### Server

**The `POST` request gets picked up by our `express` route**:

```
app.post('/api/avatar/create', saveImage, create);
```

The request hits this route: `'/api/avatar/create'`, passes through a middleware function (see below) before passing through another `saveImage` middleware function, before finally passing through to a `create` controller.

#### Client

The server sends a response back to the client. The response from our server passes through the `axios` configuration `interceptor`, which determines how to handle the `response` or the `error` that was returned from our server. It'll then pass the `response` or `error` to the `.then()` or `.catch()` of the `action` creator. The `action` creator hands it off to the `reducer`, which updates `redux` state, which then updates the `connect`ed component.

---

#### Server (microservice) setup.

Wherever you're defining your `express` middlewares (ex: `bodyParser`, `cors` or `passport` etc.), you'll want to create a `multer` middleware function (any time a file is uploaded, it passes through this function **first**):

**middlewares/index.js**

```
app.use(cors({ origin: "http://localhost:3000" }));
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(
    multer({
      limits: {
        fileSize: 10240000,
        files: 1,
        fields: 1
      },
      fileFilter: (req, file, next) => {
        if (!/\.(jpe?g|png|gif|bmp)$/i.test(file.originalname)) {
          req.err = "That file extension is not accepted!"; // this part is important, I'm attaching the err to req (which gets passed to the next middleware function => saveImage)
          next(null, false);
        }
        next(null, true);
      }
    }).single("file")
  );
...etc
```

**services/saveImage.js** (after passing through the middleware function above, the result gets passed to this `saveImage` middleware function)

```
const fs = require("fs");
const sharp = require("sharp");
const { createRandomString } = require('../../utils/helpers');

module.exports = (req, res, next) => {   
  // if the file failed to pass the middleware function above, we'll return the "req.err" as "err" or return a string if "req.file" is undefined. In short, this returns an "error.response.data.err" to the client.
  if (req.err || !req.file) {
    return res.status(400).json({ err: req.err || "Unable to process file." });
  }

  const randomString = createRandomString();

  const filename = `${Date.now()}-${randomString}-${req.file.originalname}`;
  const filepath = `uploads/${filename}`;

  const setFile = () => {
    req.file.path = filepath;
    return next();
  };

  /\.(gif|bmp)$/i.test(req.file.originalname)
    ? fs.writeFile(filepath, req.file.buffer, (err) => {
      if (err) return res.status(400).json({ "Unable to process file." });
      setFile();
    })
    : sharp(req.file.buffer)
      .resize(256, 256)
      .max()
      .withoutEnlargement()
      .toFile(filepath)
      .then(() => setFile());
};
```

If the above passes, it then passes `req` (which contains `req.file` and all its properties) to the `create` controller, which in my case, stores a path to the file (/uploads/name-of-file.ext), and a string to retrieve the image (http://localhost:4000/uploads/name-of-file.ext) to my database. In my case, that string is then sent back to the client to be stored to redux state and then updated as the user's avatar (when passing a string into an `<img src={avatarurl} alt="avatarurl.png" />`, it makes a `GET` request back to the microservice).

---

### The validation fails.

Lets say a user tried to upload a `.tiff` image. It passes through our `express` multer middleware function, which triggers the `"That file extension is not accepted!"` error, this error is returned via `req.err` to `saveImage`, which returns the `req.err` as: `return res.status(400).json({ err: req.err });`

On our client-side, that `err` flows through our axios `interceptor`:

```
avatarAPI.interceptors.response.use(
  response => response,
  error => {
    const err = get(error, ['response', 'data', 'err']); // this checks if "error.response.data.err" is present; which it is, and is now "That file extension is not accepted!"

    return err ? Promise.reject(err) : Promise.reject(error.message); // that err string gets returned to our uploadAvatar action creator's "catch" block
   },
);
```

The `uploadAvatar` action creator's `catch` block is triggered:

```
.catch(err => // our server "err" is passed to here from the interceptor
   dispatch({ type: types.SERVER_ERROR, payload: err.toString() }), // then that "err" is passed to a reducer
);
```

The `reducer` picks up the server `err` and stores it to state:

```
import * as types from 'types';

const serverInitialState = {
  error: '',
  message: '',
};

const ServerReducer = (state = serverInitialState, { payload, type }) => {
  switch (type) {
    case types.RESET_SERVER_MESSAGES:
      return { ...state, error: '' }; 
    case types.SERVER_ERROR:
      return { ...state, error: payload }; // the server err is stored to redux state as "state.server.error"
    case types.SERVER_MESSAGE:
      return { ...state, message: payload };
    default:
      return state;
  }
};

export default ServerReducer;
```

A `connect`ed component retrieves this `state.server.error` and displays it (don't worry too much about the logic here, just that it's a connected component displaying the `state.server.error` as `serverError`):

```
class RenderMessages extends Component {
  shouldComponentUpdate = nextProps =>
    this.props.serverError !== '' ||
    nextProps.serverError !== '' ||
    this.props.serverMessage !== '' ||
    nextProps.serverMessage !== '';

  componentDidUpdate = () => {
    const { serverError, serverMessage } = this.props;
    if (serverError || serverMessage) {
      const notification = serverError
        ? serverErrorMessage(serverError)
        : serverSuccessMessage(serverMessage);
      this.renderNotification(...notification);
    }
  };

  renderNotification = ({ noteType, description }) => {
    notification[noteType]({
      message: noteType === 'error' ? 'Error' : 'Update',
      description,
      icon: descriptionLayout(noteType),
    });
    setTimeout(() => this.props.resetServerMessages(), 3000);
  };

  render = () => null;
}

export default connect(
  state => ({
    serverError: state.server.error, // retrieving the error from redux state
    serverMessage: state.server.message,
  }),
  { resetServerMessages },
)(RenderMessages);
```

The final result is `That file extension is not accepted!` err is being displayed to the user:

[image]